# STL push_back: previous values getting modified when pushing a dynamically changing array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl, push-back

I am having a very strange problem with std::vector.push_back() in my CPP code. Basically, all I am doing is:

```
void func()
{
  if(first_time_coming_here)
  {
    do_some_stuff();
    V.push_back(Mat::zeros(3,1,CV_32FC1));  // OpenCV Mat structure
    V.push_back(Mat_array_that_gets_updated_in_another_function);
  }
  else
  {
    do_other_kinds_of_stuff();
    V.push_back(Mat_array_that_gets_updated_in_another_function);   
  }
}
```

Let's say the array that gets updated in the previous function is [1,1,1] initially and then the second time I execute func(), it has already become [2,2,2]. My output then should be

```
V = [ [0,0,0], [1,1,1], [2,2,2] ]
```

But instead, it is

```
V = [ [0,0,0], [2,2,2], [2,2,2] ]
```

I am really stumped as to what's going on here. The only thing that would make sense is if V is storing the CURRENT value of the array instead of what has already been passed: but once push_back() is called, shouldn't the element take the value and keep it in memory no matter what happens to the variable that is bringing the value in? V is defined as a vector of cv::Mat.

EDIT: This has been solved by clearing the value of the array between both the function calls, like:
    array = Mat::zeros(1,1,CV_32FC1);
Yet, I wonder why using it directly does not work.

Comment: Tell use how V is defined.  Probably it's a container of pointers and not a container of values.

Comment: V is defined as a vector of (cv::Mat)s.   http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did a dangerous thing, you pushed a copy of an object without respecting the pointers inside that object or the memory to which they point.  The object you pushed has memberwise assigned data members from the original, so as soon as the original object goes away, your program will crash.

The solution is to push a [clone](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-clone) of the object instead:

```
V.push_back(Mat_array_that_gets_updated_in_another_function.clone ());
```

Comment: Thank you! That explains it.

Answer (score 1):

From [the OpenCV documentation of `Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat):

> Use a copy constructor or assignment operator where there can be an array or expression on the right side (see below). As noted in the introduction, the array assignment is an O(1) operation because it only copies the header and increases the reference counter. The Mat::clone() method can be used to get a full (deep) copy of the array when you need it.

You can also see in the documentation that a `Mat` has a member `uchar* data`
where the actual data entries of the matrix are stored.

Since you did not make a deep copy of the array, changes to the original also affected the "copy" you had previously put in the `vector` as long as they
did not change where the `data` member pointed to. 
(And apparently they did not.)
But when you do something like `array = Mat::zeros(1,1,CV_32FC1);`
it appears the original `Mat` gets a new `data` pointer
(or at least I infer that it does, judging from the fact that you say the
`Mat` already in the `vector` is not altered).